# using variable with set of values inside pl/sql cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor

I am trying to use variable v_values with set of values inside cursor in the Where clause using IN operator but it returns no record.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE MyProc IS

   /* Cursor decleration */
   CURSOR CUR_DUMMY (v_values as varchar2)
   IS
        SELECT COL1,COL2,COL3 
          FROM TABLE 
             WHERE COL1 IN v_values;

   l_values varchar2();

BEGIN

   l_values:='(''one'',''two'',''three'')';

   FOR REC IN CUR_DUMMY (l_values)
   LOOP

   dbms.output.put_line(REC.col1 || ' ' || REC.col2 || ' ' || REC.col3);

   END LOOP;

END;
```

Any suggestion how to resolve this issue?

Comment: There is nothing special with comma in Oracle. Any special meaning derives purely from context. Your cursor defines a single variable.  Which may just happen to contain one or more commas, like this sentence itself, but it is still 1 sentence not three. You will have to parse the string into its components. See [how to split a comma separated string](https://blogs.oracle.com/aramamoo/how-to-split-comma-separated-string-and-pass-to-in-clause-of-select-statement).

Answer (score 2):

IN operator requires a list of values, not the values as comma delimited string.

One simple solution is using nested tables:

```
create table tab (col1,col2,col3) as
    select 'row'||rownum, 2, 3 from dual connect by level<=10
/
create or replace procedure proc is
    cursor cur (vl sys.odciVarchar2List) is
        select col1,col2,col3
        from tab
        where col1 in (select column_value val from table (vl));
begin
    for rec in cur (sys.odciVarchar2List ('row1','row3','row9')) loop
        dbms_output.put_line (rec.col1||' '||rec.col2||' '||rec.col3);
    end loop;
end;
/

SQL> exec proc
row1 2 3
row3 2 3
row9 2 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example based on Scott's `EMP` table (as I don't have yours, whose name is invalid anyway). Besides, you should pay attention to fix **obvious** errors, such as `dbms.output` (there's no dot but underline), `varchar2()` variable with no size, `v_values as` while declaring the cursor (there's no `as`) and similar stuff which are easy to fix and show that you're actually paying attention to what you're doing, and not typing *just because you must*.

Read comments within code.

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> create or replace procedure myproc is
  2     cursor cur_dummy (v_values  varchar2) is
  3       -- split V_VALUES into rows
  4       select empno, ename, job
  5       from emp
  6       where job in (select trim(regexp_substr(v_values, '[^,]+', 1, level))
  7                     from dual
  8                     connect by level <= regexp_count(v_values, ',') + 1
  9                    );
 10     l_values varchar2(100);
 11  begin
 12     -- no need to complicate with single quotes and stuff; just name those values
 13     l_values:='CLERK, MANAGER';
 14
 15     for rec in cur_dummy (l_values)
 16     loop
 17       dbms_output.put_line(rec.empno || ' ' || rec.ename || ' ' || rec.job);
 18     end loop;
 19  end;
 20  /

Procedure created.

SQL> exec myproc;
7369 SMITH CLERK
7566 JONES MANAGER
7698 BLAKE MANAGER
7876 ADAMS CLERK
7900 JAMES CLERK

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```